# Jetpack compose: Can't use Youtube API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-jetpack-compose

I'm researching for one day but didn't get any reference about youtube API with jetpack compose. is it possible to use it on jetpack compose or is there any other way to play youtube videos with jetpack compose? Please Help me

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter? For example, did you [try using `AndroidView`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)?

Comment: I found this tutorial about how to play videos with jetpack compose. I think you could use it. https://itnext.io/playing-a-video-with-jetpack-compose-10a453ff956

Comment: @CommonsWare I did it but it throws an error it says "A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context."

Comment: Does your activity extend `YouTubeBaseActivity`?

Comment: If I extend the Youtubebase activity I cant use compose. the setContent function does not work after extending Youtubebase Activity

Comment: @Tanjimahmed please add all information in your question, as is read, there is no enough information for debug, research or do anything for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, tricky one.

You cannot use YouTubeBaseActivity, means you cannot use YouTubePlayerView. This view created to work ONLY inside one activity type and does not created for your fragment/compose architecture.

You cannot use YouTubePlayerFragment, because its parent origin from android.app package, which is deprecated, you will not be able to get old fragmentManager inside your fancy compose activity.

You can and MUST use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment with compose activity fragment manager(which is instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager).

Following code works fine on my side, try it out:

```
@Composable
fun ComposeYoutube(
    modifier: Modifier,
    playList: List<String>,
    supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    onError: (String) -> Unit
) {

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = {
            var player: YouTubePlayer? = null

            val onPlaylistChangeListener = object : YouTubePlayer.PlaylistEventListener {
                override fun onPlaylistEnded() {}
                override fun onPrevious() {}
                override fun onNext() {}
            }


            val youtubeApiInitializedListener = object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                override fun onInitializationSuccess(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubePlayer?, p2: Boolean) {
                    player = p1
                    player?.setPlaylistEventListener(onPlaylistChangeListener)
                    player?.loadVideos(playList)
                }

                override fun onInitializationFailure(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?) {
                    onError("TODO")
                }
            }

            FrameLayout(it).apply {
                // select any R.id.X from your project, it does not matter what it is, but container must have one for transaction below.
                id = R.id.tv_id

                val youtubeView = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment()

                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(
                        R.id.tv_id,
                        youtubeView,
                        null
                    )
                    .commit()

                youtubeView.initialize(BuildConfig.youtubeApi, youtubeApiInitializedListener)
            }
        },
        update = { }
    )
}
```

Comment: In `add` method it will throw an exception: `Type mismatch: inferred type is YouTubePlayerSupportFragment but Fragment! was expected`.

Comment: @Dewerro this is not exception, this is compilation error. "hehe be careful" with your packages/imports. you need support fragment manager from your context, and it must be fm of import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager NOT  android.app.FragmentManager which you clearly using.

Comment: the problem is not in the support fragment manager. It occur because YouTubePlayerSupportFragment extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment, not from android.app.Fragment. But `add()` requires android.app.Fragment.

Comment: i decided to use https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player, because it's easier to use than the old youtube api.